# Passing a function to a parameter in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I added the following code to my `.emacs` file.

```
(defun delete-right-window ()
  (interactive)
  (windmove-right)
  (delete-window))

(defun delete-left-window ()
  (interactive)
  (windmove-left)
  (delete-window))

(defun delete-below-window ()
  (interactive)
  (windmove-down)
  (delete-window))

(defun delete-above-window ()
  (interactive)
  (windmove-up)
  (delete-window))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-<right>") 'delete-right-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-<left>") 'delete-left-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-<down>") 'delete-below-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-<up>") 'delete-above-window)
```

As you can see, most of the codes are repetitive. 
I read [How do I pass a function as a parameter to in elisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213267/how-do-i-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-to-in-elisp) and tried to refactor the code to passing `windmove-*` function as follow:

```
(defun delete-other-window (callback)
  (interactive)
  (funcall callback)
  (delete-window))
...

(defun delete-right ()
  (delete-other-window 'windmove-right))
```

And I bound keystroke like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-<right>") 'delete-right)
```

But when I hit `C-s-<right>` it doesn't work, only display `Wrong type argument: commandp, delete-right` in the mini buffer.

What am I missing or what should I do to work the code correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fix:

```lisp
(defun delete-after (fn)
  `(lambda () (interactive)
      (,fn)
      (delete-window)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-<right>") (delete-after 'windmove-right))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-<left>") (delete-after 'windmove-left))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-<down>") (delete-after 'windmove-down))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-<up>") (delete-after 'windmove-up))
```

Comment: Ok, here we have a user who is just starting to learn elisp. Do you really think it's a good idea to offer a solution with a function generating anonymous functions using advances tricks like lambda and backticks, especially when he already had a simple, straight forward way to implement this?

Comment: Yes. The op's implementation problem is clearly solved before the question is asked.
OP is asking for elegance and I show it to him.

Comment: Binding a lambda to a key or adding it to a hook is never elegant. When the user checks what a key is bound to or a hook contains, an anonymous lambda is like a dead end, with a pile of rubble in it (taken with a grain of salt, of course ;)

Comment: In my Emacs, `f1 k` shows the code of the anonymous lambda.
One could argue that it's even more efficient since I don't have to
jump to definition to see the source:)

Comment: Hi indydancer. IMO I expect a lot of different answer. Same answer is less valuable. Don't you think so? So abo-abo's answer is valuable for me. I think OP is just one of a people who expect answer. So you don't  need answer for just OP. If you have another possible answer, please post it. Thanks.

Comment: Although I'm new to elisp, I've studied clojure for a while and I think I can understand the proposed code. Well, using `delete-other-window` could reduce the repetitive codes, it still need to define four function looks similar and each of them should be bound respectively. So I thought I could go further after I solve this problem, this code can be my ultimatum.

Answer (score 2):

To make a function into a command, you need to add the special form `interactive` to it:

```
(defun delete-right ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-window 'windmove-right))
```

Comment: `interactive` should have been located within the function bound to keystroke. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that it's the function bind to the key that should be interactive. Not one of the function it call:

```
(defun delete-other-window (callback)
  (funcall callback)
  (delete-window))

(defun delete-right ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-other-window 'windmove-right))
```

You could also use a macro:

```
(defmacro defun-delete-other-window (direction)
  `(defun ,(intern (concat "delete-" direction)) ()
     (interactive)
     (,(intern (concat "windmove-" direction)))
     (delete-window)))

(defun-delete-other-window "right")
```

Comment: A small disadvantage of the macro approach is that you can no longer jump to
definition of e.g. `windmove-right`.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that `interactive` should be in the function that is bound to keystroke. After moving `interactive` to `delete-right`, it works well.